# How to Change Object's local Axis?

Tags: axis, transform-orientation

How can i change Local axis of this tire to be like the axis in example?
I have no idea how to do this. Is there any way i can achieve this? I'm a beginner.

If i can rotate the object without rotating the local axis, I can achieve what i need. But i don't know how to do it. Any help Appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check *Only Origins* to only transform the origin point.
It's in *Sidebar > Tool > Transform*, Shortcut: <kbd>N</kbd>

Then you can rotate the local axis, without affecting geometry.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Hi, this method works but only sometimes, it super frustrating as I can't work out what I am doing to make it work when it does work.  Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

**[Object mode]** Select the object. Shift+S > Cursor to selected. This way we'll ensure the transforms are done relative to the object pivot point. Change Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor.
**[Edit mode]** press A - it selects everything. Then press R followed by Z, X or Y, whichever axis you need to rotate object around and type 90, confirm with Enter (that's 90 degrees).

That's how you rotate object without rotating axis. Also check what **[Object mode] Ctrl+A (Apply) > Rotation** does to your axis.

Also what Jachym Michal said, that's a relatively new way to play with pivot point.