# How to change thge orientation of the object without rotating the mesh

Tags: transform-orientation

sorry in advance, I don't know a lot of the terminology for 3d and I don't know blender either but I am struggling through it.  I have two pictures here, the first shows an Empty (the orange circle) and its local orientation for Xyz.   The second a wheel and it's orientation for Xyz.  The wheel is a child of the empty (empty is the parent). I want to match the orientation of the wheel to the empty without changing the mesh position.  So I want the orientation Xyz arrow to face the same direction as it's parent.

How can I do this easily, or in as few steps as possible, I need to do it for about 20 objects, 5 for each wheel setup on the car.  The rotation for the parent empty is X=90, Y=0, Z=180 and for the other objects it all X,y and Z = 0.

Thanks

[image: ge orientation of rotation without rotating the mesh]

[image]

Comment: did you check CONTROL+A?
http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html

Comment: Hello :). This answer could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170979/

Comment: Thanks Jackym Michal, that worked

Comment: I've tried this again, in case that I made a mistake. For my simple test case where one object is parented to the empty, you can apply the rotation to the object and it doesn't rotate the mesh. Perhaps there are some information missing about your scene?

Comment: This is the answer to my problem. Thanks to Jachym Michal https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170977/how-to-change-objects-local-axis/170979#170979