# Reset object axes to object's axes of symmetry

Tags: modeling, 3d-cursor, origin, transform-orientation

I am not quite sure how, but I have managed to set the object normals to be the same as the global normals:

Axes in 'Global' mode:
[image]
This is expected.

Axes in 'Normal' mode:
[image]
I would expect one of the axes to run parallel to the length of the object.

I need the axes to be back to where they were. I understand that this cannot be done for arbitrary shapes, but in this case, the object is symmetrical around that point *only* along the normal axes that I want, so I would expect there to be a way to snap the axes back.

I certainly had the axes in the correct place at some point, I'm not sure what I did to break them.

Comment: some combination of rotating the object in edit mode and/or applying rotation in object mode, possibly

Comment: @MartyFouts Yeah, I'm pretty sure that's what caused it. How do I fix it? ;)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170977/how-to-change-objects-local-axis by hand but I don't know a way to automatically make them reset

Answer (score 1):

You must have applied the rotation of your object (its local orientation is now aligned with the global orientation). If you want to realign the local orientation with the orientation of your object faces, you can do it this way:

Select a face of your object in *Edit* mode and in the *Transform Orientations* panel click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button to create a custom orientation that is aligned with this face normal:

[image]

In the *Options* panel, enable *Only Affects > Origin* in order to be able to move and rotate the object's origin:

[image]

Go into the header menu > *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation* in order to align the origin's orientation with the custom orientation:

[image]

You can deactivate the *Only Affects > Origin* option and go back to *Global* orientation in the *Transform Orientations* panel.